# Run Python script by clicking a button on html file, get script's output into XML format

Tags: javascript, python, xml

I have python scripts that I have saved on my computer, out of curiosity I have created a html file that just has one button. Instead of going into the terminal and running python , I would like to make it so that when button is clicked, it kicks off one of my python scripts. Run the script and get the output file in XML format. Is this possible/how can it be done?

I tried js file while taking the input getting error.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and most likely there are different ways on doing it. How I have it working, more complex than a html page. I have `Django` (a Python framework) installed. In Django I have a html template with a button posting request to view.

```
...
<form method="post" action="{% url 'myap:my-template'%}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <button class="button" type="submit" name="my_flag">Run This Script</button>
</form>
...
```

In the view I import a function from a script I want to run

```
...
def MyScriptView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'my_flag' in request.POST:
        # scripts is a subdirectory with my_script.py
        from .scripts.my_script import my_script_function_to_run
        output = my_script_function_to_run
        messages.success(request, output)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:my-template'))

    return render(request, 'my-template.html')
...
```

In my_script.py's function I use Python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

```
...
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['...command to run...'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = "Error message, rc=" + str(e.returncode) + "; output=" + e.output.decode("utf-8")

return output
```

I display returned message to the same html page below the button but it can be written to xml, etc. There are Django tutorials, for example, by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django), if you chose that route.